# Re render Component when props updates (w/ Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

Ok so i have 2 components, Map and App. App component basically holds the map.

This is the code of my App:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
//Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

//Screen Imports
import CenterNew from './screens/CenterNew';
import Map from './components/Map';
import Profile from './containers/Profile';
import Review from './containers/Review';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

var store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));

class App extends Component {
 
 render () {
  
  { console.ignoredYellowBox = ['Remote debugger']; }

  const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Centers: {screen: Map},
    Review: {screen: Review},
    Profile: {screen: Profile}
  });

  MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
    title: this.props.map.title
  };

  const Screens = StackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: MainScreenNavigator},
    CenterNew: {screen: CenterNew}
  });


  return (
   <Provider store={store}>
        <Screens />
      </Provider>
     );
 }
}

const connectWithStore = (store, WrappedComponent, mapStateToProps) => {
  let ConnectedWrappedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(WrappedComponent);
  return (props) => {
    return <ConnectedWrappedComponent {...props} store={store} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  map: state.map
 };
};

App = connectWithStore(createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(thunk)), App, mapStateToProps);

export default App;
```

In the snippet, i set the title using
 `MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
          title: this.props.map.title
        };`

So whenever App is rendered, I log the initial state as you could see in `componentWillMount()` and this is the result. A syou can see, the initial title is 'Home'

[image]

now, in my Map I have a button which triggers this action creator just to change the header text:

```
this.props.changeHeaderTitle('Test');
console.log(this.props.map);
```

code:

```
export const changeHeaderTitle = (title) => {
return {
    type: 'CHANGE_HEADER_TITLE',
    payload: title
};
```

`};`

and this is my reducer:

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 isPinnable: false,
 pinnedCoordinateLatitude: 0,
 pinnedCoordinateLongitude: 0,
 region: {
     latitude: 14.582524,
     longitude: 121.061547,
     latitudeDelta: 0.007,
     longitudeDelta: 0.007
 },
 title: '',
 searched: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'ENABLE_PINNING':
   return { ... state, isPinnable: true }
  case 'DISABLE_PINNING':
   return { ... state, isPinnable: false,
    pinnedCoordinateLatitude: action.payload.latitude,
    pinnedCoordinateLongitude: action.payload.longitude }
  case 'GET_PINNED_COORDINATE':
   let test = action.payload.longitude;

   return { 
    ...state, 
    isPinnable: false,
    pinnedCoordinateLatitude: action.payload.latitude,
    pinnedCoordinateLongitude: action.payload.longitude
   }
  case 'GET_CURRENT_REGION':
   return { ...state, region: region }
  case 'CHANGE_CURRENT_REGION':
   return { ...state, region: action.payload}
  case 'CHANGE_HEADER_TITLE':
   return { ...state, title: action.payload }
  case 'SEARCHED_VIEW':
   return { ...state, searched: action.payload }
  default:
   return state;
 }
};
```

whenever the action is triggered, i know the title is updated because i log it as you can see in

```
this.props.changeHeaderTitle('Test');
```

`console.log(this.props.map);` 
[image]

but in my view, the title is still 'Home'..  I referred to this: [rerender react component when prop changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009328/rerender-react-component-when-prop-changes) and tried to use `componentWillRecieveProps()` but it is not logging when `this.props.changeHeaderTitle('Test');` action is triggered from Map component.

Comment: Show your reducer. If the state is changing, but your components are not updating, it's usually because you mutated the state object instead of returning a new one. See http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html -> "We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with Object.assign()"

Comment: I Updated my post.. i think i dont mutate the state since I am using spread operators?..

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your Redux store with your component. Therefore you should add this snippet:

```
mapStateToProps(store){
    const { title } = store; 
    return { title }; 
}    
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { changeHeaderTitle })(App)
```

The mapStateToProps function will subscribe to redux store updates. Every time your state changes, your component will rerender automatically.  You can find more information about connecting components to the redux store here:  [react-redux api docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Comment: i have updated my code snippet to include my full code.. it is already subscribed with redux

Comment: i think you forgot to inject your action creator 'changeHeaderTitle'  into the connect method, as i did in my example above.  Thats why your state doesn't change.

Comment: The 'changeHeaderTitle' action creator is invoked in Map component. The App component only recieves 'updated' the 'updated' state thru props..

Comment: so I think I don't need to inject the changeHeaderTitle() action creator because I only use it in Map Component...

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the screen title like in the code you provide.

```
 //This is only needed if you want to set the title from another screen

 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => { 
const {state} = navigation;
 return { title: `${state.params.title}`, 
}; 
}; 
ChangeThisTitle = (titleText) => { 
const {setParams} = this.props.navigation; setParams({ title: titleText }) 
} 

//Your render method
render(){
//Views goes here
 }
```

To change the title you have call the change title method from the onPress.

You may please refer this [link](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1746) for more details.

Comment: I am nesting the navigators. so I currently use this 

`MainScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'My Chats',
};` to change the title.. i got it here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting