# React, Redux & Firestore variable availability

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

Within React's componentDidMount I call some data from Firestore where an associatedID matches a string. Hard coded, everything works just fine and we add the data to the Redux store with a this.props.addStore

```
firebaseApp.firestore().collection('stores').where("associatedID", "==", "LFQ3eJZdbCUrziyoKTV1fVapa2E3").get().then((snapshot)=>{
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    let store = doc.data();

    //Tell redux
    this.props.addStore(store);
});
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(this.props.user.associatedID);
});
```

However if we were to have that associatedID as a variable pulled from Redux, then we return an error that 'the third argument of where is undefined'

```
firebaseApp.firestore().collection('stores').where("associatedID", "==", this.props.user.associatedID)
```

But in the original code you'll notice in the final .then function there is a console log of the this.props.user.associatedID which works just fine.

This suggests to me that there is a slight delay/misordering/whatever of Redux applying the state values for the component to use. Or in laymans terms the component just needs a little bit more time in componentDidMount before it can use the 'this.props.user' variable. Is there any way I can get around this without a hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is actually solvable with a comparison you can do in the componentDidUpdate lifecycle method rather than componentDidMount. Adapted from the answer 
[Re-render React component when prop changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009328/re-render-react-component-when-prop-changes/51309488#51309488)

componentDidMount was just being called too soon (before the component had access to the redux state) so the call to firestore was trying to use a variable that didn't exist yet. By checking each time the component updates we can see when it finally gets access to that variable.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.user.associatedID){
        console.log("Ok now we're good");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Still waiting!");
    }
}
```

In my console I could see four "Still waiting" and then it finally moved over to "Ok now we're good"

**FINAL UPDATE**
This actually is best solved with ComponentWillReceiveProps (now deprecated) and its replacement getDerivedStateFromProps. As in ComponentDidUpdate the solution can end up getting called multiple times. Whereas in getDerivedStateFromProps we can make a one time comparison and call out to firestore