# How to re-render a React component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component ‘A’ that depends on a value ‘x’ that is stored in the state of a provider component ‘B'. I need to re-render component ‘A’ when ‘x’ is updated. How do I achieve this? How will ‘A’ that ‘x’ has been updated? ‘B’ has very indirect access to ‘A’.

I am using an older version of React, so I can't use hooks.

Comment: Read more about react hooks or react lifecycles

Comment: How about create some example in codesandbox/codepen and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way I found was to pass the value 'x' as a prop to component 'A' so that it can automatically be re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

By updating the state of component 'B', this will triggers a re-render for the component, which will propagates to its children, including node A. React follows a drop-down architecture, meaning that updating the parent node, this will propagate it to its children.

That's a very generic answer but this is the main idea behind React rendering. You can edit you answer providing more information if you want to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I assume value 'x' is passed on as a prop to component 'A'. In that case you can do a ComponentDidUpdate check where you check the status of the props. Like so:

```
    ComponentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    //Code here 
    }
```

Check out this post: [Re-render React component when prop changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009328/re-render-react-component-when-prop-changes)