# How to render component when there is change in props React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the component if there is a change in props.

A component renders when there is `setState` but I can't `setState` in `render()` it will be in an infinite loop.

I tried to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` but since it is static I cant use forceUpdate() inside it.

My question here is how to detect the change in props and once the change is detected, how to initiate render function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-render React component when prop changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009328/re-render-react-component-when-prop-changes)

Comment: You can set the `prop` in the `state` in constructor along with that you can use `getDerivedStateFromProp` for updating the same be checking the value from existing state and new prop. This way when the prop gets updated then the component will be re-rendered

Comment: By default children components will re-render each time when props changing. Are you sure that you don't use `memo` or `PureComponent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the duplicate that Damian pointed out shows how to do it but I add a synchronous example here where initially setting state based on props is done in constructor instead of componentDidMount.

Later changes to props are detected in componentDidUpdate and will set state again with sorted data.

```js
class List extends React.PureComponent {
  sortData() {
    //only sort the data, not set the state. Shallow copy
    //  props.data because Array.prototype.sort will mutate
    //  props.data if you don't it won't cause a re render
    //  because you'll be setting state with a mutated array
    return [...this.props.data].sort(
      (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) * this.props.direction
    );
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //initially set the state with the sored data
    this.state = { data: this.sortData() };
  }

  componentDidUpdate({ direction, data }) {
    //if props.data or props.direction changed
    //  set the state again with sorted data
    if (
      this.props.direction !== direction ||
      this.props.data !== data
    ) {
      this.setState({ data: this.sortData() });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {/* not using props.data but sorted state.data */}
        {this.state.data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
function App() {
  const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setDirection((d) => (d === 1 ? -1 : 1))
          }
        >
          toggle sort direction
        </button>
      </div>
      <List data={data} direction={direction} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```